# jq merge multiple keys into one object

Tags: json, jq

I would like to make (using jq) from input:

```
{
 key1: value1,
 key2: value2,
 key3: [
  {key4: value3, key5: value5},
  {key4: value4, key5: value6},
  .
  .
  .
  {key4: valueN, key5: valueM},
  .
  .
  .
 ]
}
```

this output:

```
{
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  value3: value5,
  value4: value6,
  .
  .
  .
  valueN: valueM,
  .
  .
  .
}
```

How to do it?

I have tried some ways, but I haven't able to find the proper solution, mainly jq generated separated objects, I would like to have only one output object containing keys from input object.

Comment: What is the logic here? how would you identify all the key/value pairs? do they all start with a common prefix? e.g. like `key` in your above example

Comment: Are the sub objects present under `key3` always?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the input object, key4 and key5 are fix.

Comment: Maybe I described to issue wrongly (frankly, I don't see where is the different), but my solution for the problem was that: 
[{"": .vulnerabilities[] | {"key" : .cveId, "value": .description} } | add] | from_entries

Answer (score 2):

For the given input, the following should produce the desired output

```
.key3 as $t | del(.key3) | . + ( $t | map(to_entries | { (.[0].value) : .[1].value } ) | add )
```

[jq-play link](https://jqplay.org/s/qH5Xf_buHYr)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `reduce` on `.key3`'s items and append them successively:

```bash
reduce .key3[] as {$key4, $key5} (del(.key3); .[$key4] = $key5)
```

```json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "value3": "value5",
  "value4": "value6",
  "valueN": "valueM"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6KONuH2NQLS)

Comment: nice trick +1, but one reason I always leave out using reduce for fairly simpler solutions is the readability perspective. It gets tricky for new users to tweak it, if need for further changes

Comment: @Inian I agree that it *might* be harder to read for some (especially those used to other paradigms) but readability in general is a matter of familiarity with such concepts, so introducing them (especially to those coming from other paradigms) infact improves familiarity and, with it, readability, especially when having multiple solutions to the same problem to compare with (as we do here). So, thank you for your contribution as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

`key3` almost has the format that `from_entries` uses, tweak it?

```
.key3                 |
map(.key   = .key4)   |
map(.value = .key5)   |
map( del(.key4,.key5) )
```

Converts `key3` array to:

```
[
  {
    "key": "value3",
    "value": "value5"
  },
  {
    "key": "value4",
    "value": "value6"
  },
  {
    "key": "valueN",
    "value": "valueM"
  }
]
```

Pipe to `from_entries`:

```
( ... | from_entries) as $obj | . + $obj | del(.key3)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "value3": "value5",
  "value4": "value6",
  "valueN": "valueM"
}
```